# obtain List of dart versions via http request (or similar)

Tags: dart, version

I'm trying to build a cli app to show a list of dart versions and allow the user to select the one to install and then switch between them.

Note: there is a flutter tool (fvm) that can switch between flutter versions (and the embedded dart tools) but this tool is specifically for dart and needs versions as well as channels.

The fvm tool uses the following endpoint:
https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/releases_linux.json

But I can't find an equivalent.

Is there any method of obtaining a list of versions for each of the dart channels.

I've found:

https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels

but you need to know the full url as I can't find any endpoints that provide a list.

I'm hoping to avoid screen scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how the [Dart Archive Page](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive) retrieves all the information and use their endpoints:

The endpoints returns in a format such as:

```
{
  "kind": "storage#objects",
  "prefixes": [
    "channels/<stable|beta|dev>/release/1.11.0/",
    ...,
    "channels/<stable|beta|dev>/release/2.9.3/",
    "channels/<stable|beta|dev>/release/29803/", // You might need to filter out results such as this
    ...,
    "channels/<stable|beta|dev>/release/latest/"
    ]
}
```

Note: The results are not ordered in any way

Url:

`https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/dart-archive/o?delimiter=%2F&prefix=channels%2F<stable|beta|dev>%2Frelease%2F&alt=json`

Replace `<stable|beta|dev>` with which version do you want the info of.

If you need to collect info about a version you can use:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/<stable|beta|dev>/release/< VERSION NUMBER | latest>/VERSION`

which will return  a json object like :

```json
{
  "date": "2020-11-11", 
  "version": "2.10.4", 
  "revision": "7c148d029de32590a8d0d332bf807d25929f080e"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags for the github archive for the SDK (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tags) appear to have the releases tagged reasonably usefully.  The downside is that it is weighing in at 1.3GB, and there's no easy way to get a workable shallow clone of that.